# Extraer un string especifico de una cadena de texto - Regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, function

Estoy intentando extraer las URL que sigan el siguiente patrón: protocolo://dominio/ruta donde:

- Protocolo puede ser http o https
- El dominio está compuesto por un conjunto de letras con un '.' que separa la extensión (.com, .org, etc).
- La ruta es un conjunto de carácteres que puede contener letras o números

Por ejemplo, la web https://t.co/V3aoj9RUh4 seria una URL de interés pero una que sea del tipo http://wwww.trump.com/ no ya que tiene www y no tiene ruta.

El fichero `.csv` que estoy analizando en concreto contiene lineas como:

```
Date,Time,Tweet,Client,Client Simplified
01/20/2017, 11:56:15 PM. "THANK YOU for another wonderful evening https://t.co/V3aoj9RUh4", Twitter for iPhone, Twitter for iPhone
01/20/2017, 1:13:48 PM, "So to all Mericans, in every city near and far, small and large...https://t.co/cZKkrGXLSi", Twitter for iPhone, Twitter for iPhone
```

Como solución global, tengo que hacer una función que devuelva una tupla que contenga:

- el numero de tweets que se han hecho a través de una URL valida.
- una lista que contenga el dominio de las URLs sin repeticiones.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
import re

path= '/data/TrumpTweets.csv'
def url_validada(url):
  """Comprueba si una URL es valida

  Keyword arguments:
  url -- url a validar
  """
  url_validada = re.compile("https?:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+")
  return url_validada.search(url)

def find_interesting_urls(path, mostrar_llista=False):
    """Valida la lista de las url desde archivo
    
    Keyword arguments:
    path -- ruta al fichero del ordenador que contiene los tweets
    mostrar_llista -- indica si tenemos que mostrar la lista o no
    """
    try:
        with open(path, 'r') as inputfile:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter = ',') 
            urls = [tweets[2] for tweet in csv_reader]
            urls_validades = list(filter(url_valida,urls))
            
        # Devolvemos una tupla con la cantidad y lista de URLs si mostrar_llista es True.
        if mostrar_llista:
            resultat = (len(urls_validades), set(urls_validades))
        else:
            resultat = (len(urls_validades),)
        return resultat

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not available")
        return -1
```

El código funciona, sin embargo, en la salida estoy mostrando no solamente el dominio sino que todo. **Cómo puedo extraer el string exacto que cumpla el patrón de URL?**

La salida del código es la siguiente:

```
(6939,
 {'#Trump2016 #IACaucus Finder: https://t.co/ANvTcZ8EpQ https://t.co/gicaoEOFCC',
  'Obama opposes sanctions on Iran http://t.co/SGqN0gmc5y They are laughing at Kerry & Obama!',
  'I am on @FoxNewsSunday with Chris Wallace- his 20th year anniversary with #FNS, throughout the day. Enjoy! https://t.co/hDzdDpZiRx',
  '@MittRomney is right--this election is about jobs http://t.co/x8ph87ZN But it is interesting that @BarackObama (cont) http://t.co/t6RqfTAJ', continua....
```

Deberia ser algo como:

```
(6939, (['t.co', 'tinyurl.com'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y si usas [URLExtract](https://urlextract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `pip install URLExtract` y la librería nativa [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

```
from urlextract import URLExtract
from urllib.parse import urlparse

var = '@MittRomney is right--this election is about jobs http://t.co/x8ph87ZN But it is interesting that @BarackObama (cont) http://t.co/t6RqfTAJ | http://www.trump.com'
extractor = URLExtract()
urls = extractor.find_urls(var)
```

En este punto, `urls` será una lista: 
`['http://t.co/x8ph87ZN', 'http://t.co/t6RqfTAJ', 'http://www.trump.com']`

Ahora se pueden procesar con el método [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing) de `urllib`

```
for url in urls:
    urlobj = urlparse(url)
    print(urlobj.netloc, ' - ', urlobj.path)

# Resultado:
# t.co  -  /x8ph87ZN
# t.co  -  /t6RqfTAJ
# www.trump.com  -
```

Con eso ya puedes crear una lógica para filtrar las URL que no tienen un path hijo y las vas metiendo en un [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) para eliminar los repetidos.